# How to change variable names in partial depending on the parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial, that looks something like this

```
p Your weekly stats
  =@weekly_stats
p Your weekly shares
  =@weekly_shares
```

I would like to change these variables above by sending different name into the partial:

```
=render 'stats', period: :weekly
=render 'stats', period: :monthly
```

So that my partial will look like:

```
  p Your monthly stats
    =@montly_stats
  p Your monthly shares
    =@monthly_shares
```

I figured with simple strings it can be done this way:

```
p Your #{period.to_s.capitalize} stats
```

But how can I do that with variable names?

Comment: You could try with: eval("@" + period.to_s + "_shares")

Comment: This is possible but Im not a fan of it. using `eval` is always something that makes me nervous, especially if a part of the command executed can be influenced by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instance_variable_get` for this. It's documented here: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get

For your example it whould be like this:

```
instance_variable_get("@#{period.to_s.capitalize}_shares")
```